# What is the derivative of a max function with 3 parameters?

Tags: partial-derivative, neural-networks, backpropagation

I am not sure if this is considered a ReLU function but the function is,

```
v0 = max(h0,h1,0)
```

I need to find the derivative of v0 wrt to h0 and h1 (which are hidden layers in a convolutional neural network).
[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333394/what-is-the-derivative-of-the-relu-activation-function) explains the derivative of ReLU. But I'm not sure what to do when there are 2 or more variables.
Please help! Thank you.

Comment: The derivative of the max function is the derivative of whatever argument is currently taking the maximum value among it's arguments (unless the point in question is a point where the answer to 'which argument has the highest value?' is not unique, then the limit may not exist). The only question I'm left with is: how are $h_0$ and $h_1$ related (if at all) because you effectively need to differentiate $h_0$, w.r.t. $h_1$ and vice versa if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: If $h_0$ and $h_1$ are merely variables, then you are dealing w/ partial derivatives and in that case $\partial h_1 / \partial h_0=0$ as you treat the other variables are though they were constants when taking the partial derivative.

Comment: @JustinBenfield Oh no no, I need to partially differentiate v0 w.r.t. h0 and v0 w.r.t h1. But I did understand your point. So while differentiating w.r.t. h0, h1 becomes a constant and it'll be 1 when h0 > 0,h1.. Is this correct?

Comment: If I understand you right, you're thinking is correct. You're basically looking at differentiating max$(0,x,y)$ wrt to $x$, and $y$ respectively. In which case the result is will get is $0$ or $1$ depending on whether or not the variable you are differentiating wrt is the argument of the max function that takes the highest value or not (be careful at the endpoints though, as the derivative may not even be defined there).

Comment: @JustinBenfield Thank you very much!